# What is the alternative for sending messages without using context?

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have started to host my new bot on Heroku, via GitHub. Before hosting, I could use await client.say but I have had to use an alternative for some functions.

I am now using a client event for a delete message detector, I am wondering what the alternative 'await client.say' is, seeing as you don't have 'ctx'.

For example, I have:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def Whois(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("test")
```

I can use 'ctx' due to it being @client.command, however I can't for the following one:

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(msg):
    await client.say(msg)
```

This doesn't work during hosting due to 'await client.say' not being supported. What is the alternative without using 'ctx'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `send` to the channel the message is in

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(msg):
    await msg.channel.send(msg.content)
```